# if $A$ is a symmetric and nonnegative definite matrix then $A=LL^T$ for some $L$ lower triangular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I need help with this problem:

> Prove that if $A$ is a symmetric and nonnegative definite matrix then $A=LL^T$ for some $L$ lower triangular matrix. The terminology **nonnegative definite** means that $x^TAx\geq0$ for all $x$.

I have understood the answer for this case (2x2) [Prove that if the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\b & c\end{bmatrix}$ is nonnegative definite, then it has a factorization $LL^{T}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737020/prove-that-if-the-matrix-beginbmatrixa-b-b-c-endbmatrix-is-nonnegati) but i would want how to extend to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm grateful with any hint.

Answer (score 1):

Try mathematical induction. Suppose $A_k=\pmatrix{A_{k-1}&v_k\\ v_k^T&a_k}$. If $A_{k-1}=L_{k-1}L_{k-1}^T$ for some lower triangular matrix $L_{k-1}$, try to prove that there exist a vector $x$ and a scalar $l$ such that
$$
\pmatrix{A_{k-1}&v_k\\ v_k^T&a_k}
=\pmatrix{L_{k-1}&0\\ x^T&l}\pmatrix{L_{k-1}^T&x\\ 0&l}.
$$

Comment: What if $L_{k-1}(1,1)=0$ but $v_k(1)\neq 0$? Seems like we cannot find such an $x$ whatsoever.

Comment: @Bach If $L_{k-1}(1,1)=0$, then the first row/column of $A_{k-1}$ is zero. Since $A_k$ is positive semidefinite, the first entry of $v_k$ must be zero too. In general, since $A_k$ is positive semidefinite, $v_k$ must lie inside the column space of $A_{k-1}$. In turn, it lies inside the column space of $L_{k-1}$ as well.

Comment: How does $A_k$ being positive semidefinite imply the first entry of $v_k$ must be zero?