# Find necessary and sufficient conditions on $a,b,c$ such that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\b & c\end{bmatrix}$ has a factorization $LL^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

> Find necessary and sufficient conditions on $a,b,c$ such that the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\b  & c\end{bmatrix}$$ has a factorization $LL^{T}$ in which $L$ is lower triangular.**

I am using the following to demonstrate this:

- [Prove that if the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\b & c\end{bmatrix}$ is nonnegative definite, then it has a factorization $LL^{T}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737020/prove-that-if-the-matrix-beginbmatrixa-b-b-c-endbmatrix-is-nonnegati)
- [Find the precise conditions on $a,b,c$ so that $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is nonnegative definite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734318/find-the-precise-conditions-on-a-b-c-so-that-left-beginsmallmatrixab-c/2734951#2734951)

With the above, can I conclude that the necessary and sufficient conditions must be the following?

$$a \geq 0, \quad c \geq 0, \quad b^2 \leq ac$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The conditions are necessary and sufficient. Look at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those conditions are sufficient and necessary.

A remark is that $$a \ge 0, b^2 \le ac \implies c \ge 0$$